# How to comment multiple lines in Lighttpd config file?

Tags: lighttpd

In lighttpd.conf usually comment 1 line with #

How was wondering how to comment multiple lines without adding # in front of each line.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since [the lighttpd documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:Configuration) doesnt show something like this in the syntax documentation, i dont think this is possible.

however, your editor may have a function to put a # in front of every line you select :)

Answer (score 4):

You could pull the lines out into a separate.conf file and then in the main file do:

```
include "separate.conf"
```

Then you have a single line that you can comment in/out as you wish with a #.

Not precisely what you want, but depending on why you want to do it, that might be of use.

Answer (score -5):

This is PHP, correct? If so you would just use:

> /* This is the start of my comment
>
> This is more of my comment. This is
>
> the end of my comment. */

Good luck.

Comment: No it is the webserver configuration file. How can be php if I use # on a single line ?